# MapStruct how to conditionally drop members of a collection

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a parent DTO class that has a list of child DTO objects. I am using MapStruct mappers to map both classes from their entities. This all works fine and looks something like this:

```
class ParentDTO {
    String afield;
    List<ChildDTO> children; 
    //getters & setters
}
class ChildDTO{
    Instant theDate; 
    //getters & setters
}


@Mapper(uses = {ChildMapper.class})
public interface ParentMapper {
   ParentDTO entityToDTO(ParentEntity parent);
}

@Mapper
public interface ChildMapper {
   ChildDTO entityToDTO(ChildEntity child);
}
```

Is there a way for me to exclude members of the list of ChildDTOs where "theDate" is in the past?

Tried using @Mapping with annotation with "source" attribute - but could not get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MapStruct: filter a list before mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424178/mapstruct-filter-a-list-before-mapping)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65801193/mapstruct-ignore-some-elements-of-a-collection-based-on-the-value-of-one-of-the

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci - That looks like it would work - but I went a different way

Answer (score 0):

figured how to do this with @BeforeMapping to filter the List before it gets mapped.

```
@BeforeMapping
    protected void removeExpired(ParentEntity parent, @MappingTarget ParentDTO parentDTO) {
        if (!parent.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            Instant currentTime = Instant.now();
            List<Child> children = parent.getChildren().stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getTheDate().isAfter(currentTime))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList();
            parent.setChildren(children);
        }
    }
```

Also had to change mapping interface into an abstract class.

Comment: Mapstruct supports interface default methods, no needs to move to abstract class